# Ember 2.7 model inheritance - how to access data in the template that comes from a model related to parent?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-components

In Ember 2.7 assume you have a `Person` class that has an `Address` model (assume `city:DS.attr()` is the only attribute).

app/models/person.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr(),
  lastName: DS.attr(),
  fullName: Ember.computed('firstName', 'lastName', function() {
    return `${this.get('lastName')}, ${this.get('firstName')}`;
});
```

An `Employee` inherits from `Person` and adds a status field (like hired, retired, fired, etc.)

app/models/employee.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

import Person from '../models/person';

export default Person.extend({
  status: DS.attr(),
  statusCode: DS.attr(),
});
```

In a component that is displaying the `Employees`, like this:

app/templates/components/employee-list.hbs

```
{{#each employees as |employee|}}
<div>
  <h2>{{employee.fullName}}</h2>
  <p>Home Base : [city]</p>
  <p>Status : {{employee.status}}</p>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

What is the EmberJS way to get at the address of this `Employee` (ie. this '`Person`') so that the template can show the city of this person from the Address model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{employee.address.city}}` is the handlebars code that's needed:

```
{{#each employees as |employee|}}
<div>
  <h2>{{employee.fullName}}</h2>
  <p>Home Base : {{employee.address.city}}</p>
  <p>Status : {{employee.status}}</p>
</div>
{{/each}}
```